# hgweb.cgi 404 not found

Tags: apache, mercurial

I've been like 20hs trying to resolve this.

I had a perfectly running system with Redmine + Mercurial.

Then I virtualized it and reinstalled everything.

Redmine now works, but Mercurial won't.

It always throws 404 Not Found or 500 Internal Server Error (if the repo name is bad).

I've tried many things, including removing Redmine authentication.

repos.tracker.conf in sites-enabled:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName repos.tracker.intranet.****.com.ar
 DocumentRoot /var/www/repos.dev01/
 ServerAlias www.repos.tracker.intranet.****.com.ar repos.****.com.ar
 ServerAdmin jsivil@****.com.ar
 LogLevel warn
 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/repos_error
 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/repos_access combined

 PerlLoadModule Apache2::Redmine
 #PerlLoadModule Apache::DBI
 ScriptAliasMatch "^/hg(.*)" "/opt/repos/hgwebdir.cgi$1"
 <LocationMatch "^/hg">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Redmine Mercurial Repository"
    Require valid-user

    #Redmine auth
    PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
    PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
    RedmineDSN "DBI:mysql:database=redmine;host=127.0.0.1"
    RedmineDbUser "redminedb"
    RedmineDbPass "redminepass"
 </LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

tracker.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin jsivil@****.com.ar
        ServerName tracker.intranet.****.com.ar
        ServerAlias www.tracker.intranet.****.com.ar
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev01
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/dev01>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/opt/repos/hgweb.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
#
# An example hgweb CGI script, edit as necessary
# See also https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories

# Path to repo or hgweb config to serve (see 'hg help hgweb')
config = "/opt/repos/hgweb.config"
# Uncomment and adjust if Mercurial is not installed system-wide
# (consult "installed modules" path from 'hg debuginstall'):
#import sys; sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/python/lib")

# Uncomment to send python tracebacks to the browser if an error occurs:
#import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb, wsgicgi
application = hgweb(config)
wsgicgi.launch(application)
```

/opt/repos/hgweb.config

```
[paths]
/=/opt/repos/hg/**

[web]
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false
allowbz2 = yes
allowgz = yes
allowzip = yes
baseurl = /hg
```

Permissions:

```
root@tracker:/opt/repos/hg# ls -la
total 16
drwxrw-r-- 4 www-data root 4096 ene  1 15:37 .
drwx------ 3 www-data root 4096 ene  1 15:37 ..
drwxrw-r-- 3 www-data root 4096 oct  5 21:35 animalizate
drwxrw-r-- 3 www-data root 4096 oct  5 22:11 mercurial-hooks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally fixed the error.

I used the script present in /usr/share/doc/mercurial/examples/hgweb.wsgi

Then the 404 error went away.